# Redirect www to non-www using Apache htaccess does not work

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I have this in my *.htaccess* (modified from the default Drupal *.htaccess*):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website.com\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

In theory this will redirect something like `http://www.website.com/asdf` to `http://website.com/asdf`. However, it doesn't redirect, it allows requests to go through like there was no redirect intended.

(I'm on OS X if it matters, but I've also tried it on a Network Solutions Linux server with the same result.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable the rewrite engine in your .htaccess file if you have not done already...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Note that I've removed the extra `.com` on the `RewriteCond` line that you have in your question - I'm assuming this was a typo?

Also, `FollowSymLinks` must also be enabled, if not already (should appear before the above)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

If it's still not doing anything then it's possible the .htaccess file (or these directives) are not being processed at all. (You can test this by typing some nonsense and see if it breaks!) In which case, look for the `AllowOverride` directive in your server config / virtual host settings and set this to `AllowOverride All` (it might be set to `None` for instance) - or query this with your host.

Comment: They are both in the `.htaccess` a few lines earlier

Comment: If you are not on a live server then you can make an obvious syntax error to see if your site breaks! If not then the file (or these directives) are not being processed at all. In which case, look for the `AllowOverride` directive in your server config / virtual host and set this to `AllowOverride All` - or query this with your host. (Although I'm a bit puzzled why this wouldn't be enabled at Network Solutions, so maybe this is not the problem?!)

Comment: I have tried just typing random stuff to ensure it's being parsed, and it is. Also, I know it is read because my Drupal URL's don't include the `index.php?q=`, which is less than five lines later in the `.htaccess`. The duplicated `.com` was just a typo when changing the URL. I've tried a few different variations of this from around the web, and none of them seem to work. I'm really at a loss here as to what the issue is...

Comment: In that case, there is something else in your .htaccess file (or your code) that is preventing this from redirecting. The code you have posted is OK in itself. This code is presumably at the top of your .htaccess file? And you have a single .htaccess file in the root of your site?