# htaccess redirect for directory listing to virtual host on a local MAMP stack

Tags: htaccess, mamp

For my local dev environment, I have just upgraded from MAMP to MAMP Pro so that I can easily create virtual hosts without getting too involved with configuration files. Server names will be formatted as: `foldername.localhost`

For my site's directory I want to create an htaccess rule to redirect from `http://localhost/foldername` to `http://foldername.localhost`, where "foldername" is a wildcard.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =localhost
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(.*) http://$1.localhost$2 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect `http://localhost/foldername/path/to/file` to `http://foldername.localhost/path/to/file` (where `/path/to/file` is optional).

There are two parenthesised sub patterns for the "foldername" (`$1`) and "URL path" (`$2`).

The second `RewriteCond` directive checks to see whether the first part of the URL is a valid directory.

Comment: I have multiple sites in various folders hence the requirement for foldername to be a wildcard. Is the solution above such that I would need to create a rule for each site?

Comment: It did. I've changed it to be more general.

Comment: I've updated (fixed) the code... the `RewriteCond` directive wasn't checking the local filesystem path.

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this, but so far your solution is not working for me.

Comment: In what way is it not working? Is it redirecting anything? Is there anything else in your .htaccess file that it might be conflicting with?

Comment: It just isn't redirecting I'm afraid. There is nothing else at all in the htaccess file. Could this be an incompatibility with MAMP?

Comment: MAMP is Apache, so there shouldn't be a problem. Does a simple redirect such as `RewriteRule .* http://google.com [R,L]` do anything? If nothing, then check that mod_rewrite is loaded and the things mentioned in this other answer (`Options`, `AllowOverride`, etc.): http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55231/1243

Comment: Your suggestion of the google redirect works fine. But I can not get the other rule to work. I must be missing something really basic